# Why is typescript complaining when a /// reference is after 'use strict'?

Tags: typescript, commonjs, use-strict, typescript1.7

This question is some what related to [Why is typescript failing to import a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35321840/why-is-typescript-failing-to-import-a-module/35322290#35322290), which I asked yesterday. The initial setup is the same.

I have a simple typescript file like this:

```
/// <reference path="./typings/js-yaml/js-yaml.d.ts"/>
'use strict';
import * as y from 'js-yaml';
console.log(y);
```

When I compile like so `tsc --module commonjs file.ts`, typescript is happy.

But, when I move the /// reference below the 'use strict', like this:

```
'use strict';
/// <reference path="./typings/js-yaml/js-yaml.d.ts"/>
import * as y from 'js-yaml';
console.log(y);
```

Typescript is not happy:

```
$ tsc --module commonjs file.ts 
file.ts(4,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'js-yaml'.
```

Typescript does indeed output a compiled file and it is the same as the one output originally, except of course that the /// reference is after 'use strict' in the second case.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb385682.aspx#ReferenceDirectives),

> The following rules apply to a reference directive.
>   The reference XML comment must be declared before any script.

This may be the reason.

Comment: That's part of it perhaps. But, this looks like it is for javascript in VisualStudio. It is not a reference about typescript.

Answer (score 1):

There is a note about `<reference>` tag in TypeScript [specification](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#1111-source-files-dependencies):

> A comment of the form `/// <reference path="…"/>` that occurs before the
>   first token in a source file adds a dependency on the source file
>   specified in the path argument. The path is resolved relative to the
>   directory of the containing source file.

Answer (score 1):

Reference directives have to be at the top of the file. When they're not at the top, they're ignored. This causes the module resolution to fail, because otherwise the compiler has no idea to go looking in some other random folder for the definition of the `js-yaml` module.

The reason for the restriction is simply performance: It's actually very slow (we tried!) to try to parse every single comment in a file to see if it's a reference directive or not.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. It would be nice if this were mentioned more explicitly in the handbook. I didn't even think to go and read the specification. I can make a PR for that if the handbook is on github.